# Why is the production.log not being written to, are the permissions off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, passenger, ubuntu-10.10

I just installed rails on ubuntu 10.10 and I am running into a problem and i cant check the production.log because its empty. I have passenger and the permissions for production.log is 777 and still nothing. I have no idea how to fix this and i tried even changing the user like this

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R logs/
```

and

```
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu -R logs/
```

and still nothing ...any ideas

UPDATE after running `ps auxw | less`

```
mysql      544  0.0  3.1 156112 19408 ?        Ssl  02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root       607  0.0  0.5   7392  3092 ?        Ss   02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       609  0.0  0.2   4388  1652 ?        Ssl  02:15   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root       614  0.0  0.3  15776  1832 ?        Sl   02:15   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
root       617  0.1  1.0  17936  6252 ?        Sl   02:15   0:03 Passenger spawn server                                                                                                                                          
nobody     620  0.0  0.4   9608  3048 ?        Sl   02:15   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
www-data   630  0.0  0.5   7816  3384 ?        S    02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   631  0.0  0.5   7568  3200 ?        S    02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   632  0.0  0.5   7824  3368 ?        S    02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   633  0.0  0.5   7816  3368 ?        S    02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   634  0.0  0.5   7808  3392 ?        S    02:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       651  0.0  0.0   1860   564 tty1     Ss+  02:15   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root       719  0.0  0.5   8852  3116 ?        Ss   02:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
root       722  0.0  0.4  19996  2940 ?        Sl   02:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
ubuntu     814  0.0  0.2   8852  1372 ?        S    02:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0  
ubuntu     815  0.0  0.9   8948  6004 pts/0    Ss   02:16   0:00 -bash
root       875  0.0  0.5   8852  3112 ?        Ss   02:19   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
ubuntu     905  0.0  0.2   8852  1376 ?        S    02:19   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/1  
ubuntu     906  0.0  0.9   8904  5828 pts/1    Ss+  02:19   0:00 -bash
www-data   973  0.0  0.5   7816  3448 ?        S    02:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu     975  0.0  7.5  61256 45772 ?        S    02:20   0:00 Rails: /var/www/umaniweb.com                                                                                                                                    
www-data   977  0.0  0.5   7816  3360 ?        S    02:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   978  0.0  0.5   7816  3344 ?        S    02:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   979  0.0  0.5   7816  3364 ?        S    02:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: updating my question with the response

Comment: seems like there is a www-data and an ubuntu and root...its hard to tell which to use

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I was looking at the logs folder when rails needs log...